# How to format variant.versionCode to include leading "0"?

Tags: android-studio, string-formatting, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using custom gradle to rename output apk file name:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                output.outputFile.name.replace("app-release", "myApp-${variant.versionCode}-${variant.versionName}"))
    }
}
```

I need to format the version code like using `printf("%05d", versionCode);`

Is it possible?

Comment: Use Java's `string.format()`?

Comment: @ScottBarta something like this: String.format("%03d", variant.versionCode); ? Is it the correct syntax?

Comment: @ScottBarta easy, it works. If you turn your comment into an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: You have the more complete answer -- go ahead and write it up. I don't deserve 25 points for a 4-word comment ;)

Comment: @ScottBarta You're a true gentlemen ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that using `String.format("%03d", variant.versionCode)'` does, in fact, add the leading 0s.  Props to @seraphim